# How do I convert a six-digit input to a date format in vue/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Been looking at various solutions for this, but they all seem to be backend-related.
I am looking for a Vue/JavaScript method.
I have a string that contains ID's. The first 6 digits are date of birth, and the final 4 are a personal number, so an ID will look something like this:

211089-0000

So the first 6 digits represent DD/MM/YYYY.

I have two fields: one where the ID is entered and one that contains date of birth. I would like for the date of birth field to be updated when an ID has been entered, using the first 6 digits and converting them into a date format.

This is how far I have gotten:

I have a computed method that looks like this:

```
  updateDateOfBirth(){
    if(!this.dateOfBirth && this.userId > 6){
      return this.dateOfBirth = this.userId.substring(0,6)
    }
  }
```

And I added it as a change event in the userId input form

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-form-input v-model="userId" @change="updateDateOfBirth" placeholder="Enter your ID"></b-form-input>
    <div class="mt-2">Value: {{ userId }}</div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <b-form-datepicker id="dateOfBirth" v-model="dateOfBirth" class="mb-2"></b-form-datepicker>
    <p>Value: '{{ dateOfBirth }}'</p>
 </div>
</template>
```

But I need to convert the 5th and 6th digits into a year format, so 211089 becomes 21/10/1989.

Is it something that can be done by moment.js maybe? I have not been able to find any good examples.

Comment: would "adding 1900" work? But then, is "05" really "1905" or "2005"?

Comment: This is not a Y2K sane date representation.

Comment: Well if you are able to extract the digits from position 0 to 5 ... then you should also be able to extract those from 0 to 3, and those from 4 to 5 separately - and then concatenate them with the century part inserted between them. But as was mentioned, you will probably need to implement a logic to determine whether the century is supposed to be `19`, or `20`. Which range of two-digit years is supposed to be in which century, is a thing that whoever came up with this date format, would need to _specify_.

Answer (score 0):

[Vue SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

I did it in Composition API, just port to Options API, and change ot your date picker format, I used a standard `input[type=date]`.

1. Use `watch` instead of `@change` since you already have a model for the ID input
2. Get date parts with a regex
3. Validate against `Date`
4. Set the error or datepicker value accordingly:

```
<script setup>
import { ref, watch } from 'vue'

const userId = ref('');
const dateOfBirth = ref('');
const error = ref('');

watch(userId, userId => {
  error.value = '';
  const match = userId.match(/^(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})/);
  if(match){
    let [_, d, m, y] = match;
    const curr = new Date().getFullYear().toString().slice(-2);

    y = (y > curr && y < 100 ? 1900 : 2000) + +y;
    const val = `${y}-${m}-${d}`; // make your own format
    // validate date here - convert to date and compare to the format
    const dt = new Date(y, m - 1, d, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    const formatted = `${dt.getFullYear()}-${dt.getMonth() + 1}-${dt.getDate()}`;
    if(formatted !== val){
      error.value = 'Invalid ID date format';
    } else {
      dateOfBirth.value = val;
    } 

  }
});

</script>


<template>
  <div>
    <input v-model="userId" placeholder="Enter your ID">
    <div style="color:red" class="error">{{error}}</div>
    <div class="mt-2">Value: {{ userId }}</div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="date" id="dateOfBirth" v-model="dateOfBirth" class="mb-2">
    <p>Value: '{{ dateOfBirth }}'</p>
 </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use moment js

```
<script>
import MC from './components/MC.vue';
import moment from 'moment';

export default {
  name: 'App',
  moment: moment,
  components: {
    MC,
  },
  computed: {
    timestamp: function () {
      return moment('211089', 'DDMMYY').format('DD/MM/YYYY')
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.